# git bash not showing the desired prompt

Tags: git-bash

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8EmG.png)
[how it looked before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7lpk.png)

So I have not used my git bash shell in a while and it was working perfectly fine, but when I opened it today I noticed that the terminal interface looked different and it appeared that it had logged me out and forgot my credentials (hence the /usr/bin/bash --login -i on top).

I'm not sure if anyone else has encountered this issue, but it's very irritating because even though I can still technically access all my folders and the features of git bash (oddly enough) I can't see any of the directory names and it's just impossible to work with in general.

I've tried everything under the sun (googling not-stop, uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, logging in and logging out with the "config" commands, etc.) yet the issue still persists...

I'm not super knowledgeable on all of this so I may not even know the extent of what's going on or what the problem really is, but if anyone does please help!

Comment: What operating system are you on? What terminal application are you using?

Comment: @AndyRay "Git bash", mentioned in the title and in tags, doesn't leave much to guess.

Comment: What does it say when you type `whoami` ?

Comment: @Mike Kim When I type "whoami" it displays the correct user (Isaiah)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is actually a bash issue rather than a Git one, though you probably want to use one of the various Git-related bash prompt-setters, such as the one in [tymtam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74792501/1256452).

Answer (score 1):

Normally the git prompt is controlled by `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh` and it should contain these lines:

```
if test -f ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
then
    . ~/.config/git/git-prompt.sh
else
    PS1='\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]' # set window title
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[32m\]'       # change to green
    PS1="$PS1"'\u@\h '             # user@host<space> <--- This gives you Isaiah@computer_name
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[35m\]'       # change to purple
    PS1="$PS1"'$MSYSTEM '          # show MSYSTEM
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[33m\]'       # change to brownish yellow
    PS1="$PS1"'\w'                 # current working directory
    if test -z "$WINELOADERNOEXEC"
    then
        GIT_EXEC_PATH="$(git --exec-path 2>/dev/null)"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${GIT_EXEC_PATH%/libexec/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="${COMPLETION_PATH%/lib/git-core}"
        COMPLETION_PATH="$COMPLETION_PATH/share/git/completion"
        if test -f "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
        then
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-completion.bash"
            . "$COMPLETION_PATH/git-prompt.sh"
            PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[36m\]'  # change color to cyan
            PS1="$PS1"'`__git_ps1`'   # bash function
        fi
    fi
    PS1="$PS1"'\[\033[0m\]'        # change color
    PS1="$PS1"'\n'                 # new line
    PS1="$PS1"'$ '                 # prompt: always $
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Date modified" on these to see if any have been changed recently:

(especially these two):

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bashrc
```

(also): under C:\Program Files\

```
/Git/etc/profile.d/bash_profile.sh
/Git/etc/profile.d/git-prompt.sh
/Git/etc/bash.bashrc
/Git/etc/profile
/Git/etc/profile.d/aliases.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Git Bash. That worked for me (when none of the other answers here did).